# Apply function to elements of a list while condition with function's result is true

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I need iterating over a list while condition is true. I done that by function `iterc` below:

```
let data = [12; 3; 4; 56; 7]
let restriction = 146
let convert elem = pown elem 2 + 1

let rec iterc (cond : ('T -> bool)) (action : ('T -> unit)) (list : 'T list) =
    match list with
    | head::tail ->
        match (cond head) with
        | true ->
            action head
            iterc cond action tail
        | false -> ()
    | [] -> ()

iterc ((>) restriction << convert)
      (printfn "%A" << convert)
      data

> 145
  10
  17
```

I don't like that `convert` is used twice. The same expression is computed in `cond` and in `action`. How to solve this problem more properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are existing F# functions that seem to do what you want.
You can write most of what you have above like this:

```
let data = [12; 3; 4; 56; 7]
let restriction = 146
let convert elem = pown elem 2 + 1

for value in data |> Seq.map convert |> Seq.takeWhile ((>) restriction) do
    printfn "%A" value
```

Comment: Thanks, but you have a bug  with currying - it should be `((>) restriction)`

Comment: Thanks, @Feofilakt, I've edited the answer to use the correct operator.

Answer (score 3):

Is your attempted solution supposed to ignore the data point that is 7? I assumed otherwise. Squimmy's posted solution has a bug because it is using `Seq.takeWhile` instead of `Seq.filter` or `Seq.where`. What you probably want is the following:

```
let data = [12; 3; 4; 56; 7]
let restriction = 146
let convert elem = pown elem 2 + 1

data |> List.map (fun value -> convert value ) 
     |> List.filter (fun value -> value < restriction) 
     |> List.iter(fun value -> printfn "%A" value)
```

returns

```
145
10
17
50
```

Comment: That last `List.map` should probably be `List.iter`

Comment: @Ringil Yes, I wanted to ignore the value for 7. I looked at `List` module and didn't guess that there is `Seq.takeWhile`. The final version is: `data |> List.map (convert) |> Seq.takeWhile ((>) restriction) |> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")`

Comment: Seems it should be `data |> Seq.map (convert) |> Seq.takeWhile ((>) restriction) |> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")` to prevent unnecessary computing.